# Documentation for the embedded cue point format of Traktor/Serato/Ableton/

Tags: software, ableton-live, dj, traktor

Most DJ software these days lets you set cue points. These are typically stored somewhere in the ID3 tags (assuming you're using mp3). Unfortunately, manufacturers seem to use GEOB (an opaque datatype) for this.

Is there any recommended way to programmatically read and write cue points from/to mp3 files? Some tool? Or any documentation on what format each program uses?

#### Update 8/2019

Serato GEOB tags have been mostly [reverse engineered](https://github.com/Holzhaus/serato-tags). Traktor and Ableton are still missing.

Comment: Should be migrated to http://sound.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KolobCanyon If that helps getting an answer... yes, please!

Comment: Would but I don't have the rep :(

Comment: i dont know about putting cue points, but you can label it in timestamp with lyrics http://www.shadesofsolveig.com/2014/02/20/how-to-edit-your-mp3-music-metadata/